# set up trac with wsgi

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf, trac

I have followed the following steps

1. downlaod trac 1.0.9
2. install using `python2.7 ./setup.py install` . this is a altinstall of python on centos 6 64 bit
3. created repository on `trac-admin operationalintelligence initenv`
4. trying to set up apache but not working

I have selinux enabled and have run `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /usr/share/trac`

> ```
> <  Location /trac/operationalintelligence  >
>
>
>
>    SetHandler mod_python
>
>    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
>
>    PythonOption TracEnv "/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence"
>
>    PythonOption TracUriRoot "/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence"
>
>    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
>
>    PythonInterpreter trac
> </Location>
> ```

Apache fails when trying to restart.

with the following config i am recieving the error below

```
Invalid command 'PythonInterpreter', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration


#Alias /trac /usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence

#<Directory /usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence>
#   SetHandler mod_python
#   PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
#   PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
#   PythonOption TracEnv /usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence
#   PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
#</Directory>
```

I have now tried wsgi configuration which is progressing

```
 WSGIScriptAlias /trac /usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi

<Directory /usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    # For Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    # For Apache 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

The error i receive in httpd error log is

```
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:52 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] mod_wsgi (pid=30558): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:52 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:52 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6]   File "/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi", line 30, in application
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:52 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6]     from trac.web.main import dispatch_request
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:52 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] ImportError: No module named trac.web.main
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:58 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] mod_wsgi (pid=30553): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:58 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:58 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6]   File "/usr/share/trac/operationalintelligence/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi", line 30, in application
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:58 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6]     from trac.web.main import dispatch_request
[Thu Feb 04 17:40:58 2016] [error] [client 47.73.16.6] ImportError: No module named trac.web.main
^C
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with ModPython looks to be due to mod_python not being loaded. Try:

```
a2enmod mod_python
```

The problem with WSGI looks to be due to the Trac package not being found on your Python path. It could be a permissions issue.

Comment: If you installed Trac as a non-root user, then it may have been installed into a user-specific Python directory where your webserver (running as a separate user) can't access it.  If this is indeed the problem, then installing Trac as the superuser should resolve it.

Comment: I have used root user and I am using centos. i installed trac using `python setup install` command so where is trac folder to chmod?

Comment: It's dependent on your Linux distribution and Python version, but you may have: `/usr/bin/tracd`, `/usr/bin/trac-admin` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac`. You might also look in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ownership of python's files helped me:

```
chown -R wwwrun /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```